# MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json

Tags: java, jersey

Добрый день.
Пишу клиент-сервеное приложение с использованием Jersey. Возникла проблема получить данные на клиенте -- не удаётся автоматически передать объект класса.

Как я понимаю, нужно написать свой провайдер https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html, что и было сделано. Тем не менее я получаю ошибку:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=interface java.util.List, genericType=java.util.List<com.example.model.HotelsEntity>.
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:225)
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1124)
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:853)
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:812)
org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:377)
org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:813)
org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$600(JerseyInvocation.java:90)
org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$3.call(JerseyInvocation.java:693)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:689)
org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:405)
org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:301)
com.example.service.HotelService.getHotels(HotelService.java:30)
com.example.actions.HotelAction.perform(HotelAction.java:43)
com.example.utils.MainServlet.processResponse(MainServlet.java:34)
com.example.utils.MainServlet.doPost(MainServlet.java:23)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Провайдер:

```
@Provider
public class JsonCollection extends JsonProvider<Collection<? extends HospitalityEntity>> {
}

public class JsonProvider<T> implements MessageBodyReader<T>, MessageBodyWriter<T> {

@Override
public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.equals(mediaType.getType()) &&
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.equals(mediaType.getSubtype());
}

@Override
public T readFrom(Class<T> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    Gson gson = createGson();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entityStream, Charset.forName(Constants.UTF_8));
    return gson.fromJson(reader, genericType);
}

@Override
public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.equals(mediaType.getType()) &&
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.equals(mediaType.getSubtype());
}

@Override
public long getSize(T t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return -1;
}

@Override
public void writeTo(T t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    Gson gson = createGson();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(entityStream);
    Writer writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream, Charset.forName(Constants.UTF_8));
        gson.toJson(element, writer);
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.flush();
        }
    }
}

private Gson createGson() {
    return new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
}
```

Обращение к серверу:

```
     GenericType<List<HotelsEntity>> genericType = new GenericType<List<com.example.model.HotelsEntity>>(){};
    WebTarget target = client.target(preparePath())
            .queryParam("checkIn", checkin)
            .queryParam("checkOut", checkout)
            .queryParam("capacity", capacity).;
    List<HotelsEntity> hotels = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(genericType);
```

Есть ли у вас идеи, что здесь не так?

Спасибо.